# Align text and button inside td based on that text lenght

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I got a table where i iterate some database records, basically i got a td where i put a text (corresponding to every record status), and a button that opens that record detail like this:

```
{% for item in records %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ item.status }}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-xs btn_request_detail" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ver detalle" code = "" data-url="{% url 'unbinding:management_detail' item.id %}" >
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-md text-light-blue"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When every records has the same status text , the entire column aligns perfectly, but if any of those status text change in lenght, the button moves to the right and i lost the alignment.

Is there any way that the buttons aling vertically in the table based on the text lenght ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move your "cta" (button) to a new column?

I think you should do that.

Please, try this:

```
{% for item in records %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ item.status }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-xs btn_request_detail" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ver detalle" code = "" data-url="{% url 'unbinding:management_detail' item.id %}" >
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-md text-light-blue"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

PS. don't forget to add one more  or  to yours table head.

Comment: Yes, i tried that but the result it's awfull due to tha quantity of columns per record, and also, every th has filters...thanks anyway man !

Comment: Strange. Every table you can fix with css help (for style). But if you can't add one more column in your table had, just add *colspan* to your latest th.